# Count no of lines in a file/ PCollection using apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have a PCollection with log of rows some contains [xyz] and others contains [abc]. Need to count the no of lines contains [xyz] and [abc] separately.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Metrics](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics) for this purpose - just create two different counters for [abc] and [xyz], increment them accordingly and get the result from `PipelineResult` after your pipeline was finished. More details with examples are are in [Beam metrics documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics).